# Можно ли передать функции параметром какое-то свойство?

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать параметры функции, везде в пример приводят либо строки, либо числа. Мне от интересно стало, можно ли передавать свойства. К примеру:

```
 `document.querySelector('.btn_add').onclick = _ => {
    blure(a);
}

document.querySelector('.btn_remove').onclick = _ => {
    blure(a);
}

function blur(a) {
    let p = document.querySelectorAll('p');
    for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        p.classList.add('blur');
    }
}`
```

Я хочу вместо `add` подставлять переменную `a`, первой кнопке параметром задать `add`, второй `remove`. Только не могу понять как это делается.

Comment: `p.classList[a]`, переменная `a` соответственно строка `add || remove`, в чем тут проблема. Свойства и есть строковые идентификаторы(или символьные), просто указываются в квадратных скобках. К примеру `classList['add']` идентично `classList.add`

Comment: вместо ` = _ => {` пиши лучше так: `=()=>{`

Comment: Действительно, спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая что `p.classList.add('blur');`

тоже самое что `p.classList["add"]('blur');`

Думаю я дал ответ на твой вопрос